# Which test would I use in this situation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, group-differences

I have a sample of people, $n=300$. All $300$ should be offered both of two therapeutic treatments (Treatment A and B). I will be collecting data on how many people were offered A only, B only, and A and B. All three values *should* be $300$ or $100\%$ (although I know they won't be).

Is there a way to test the significance of the values I get? Which test would I use?

Comment: Why would you want to test significance here?

Comment: What's your null hypothesis?

Comment: Set aside the word "significant" which often leads to muddled thinking. What do you want to learn from your data? What generalization could you make?  Try to answer without "significant", or "null hypothesis". What is the scientific quesion?